# Is is possible to use operators under literals?

Tags: regex, julia

Suppose I have the following function

```
fx(label, text) = match(Regex("\\W*\\Q$label\\E\\s*(.*)"), text).captures[]
text1 = "IAREA aoi/IA_1.ias"
```

The result of the first function call

```
fx("IAREA (?!FILE)", text1)
```

is expected (probably with a wrong reason), because string "IAREA" is not followed by "FILE" in `test1`.

But the result of the second function call

```
fx("IAREA (?!MMM)",  text1)
```

is not expected: Because "IAREA" in "text1" is NOT followed by "MMM", this function call should return `aoi/IA_1.ias`, but it returns nothing.

I'm wondering: Is it possible to achieve this by changing the `label` argument, not by changing the function body?

Comment: Your `$label` is wrapped with `\Q` and `\E`, where all chars are treated literally. Remove the `\Q` and `\E` operators if you pass a regex, `Regex("\\W*$label\\s*(.*)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass a regex pattern to the regex constructor, you needn't use  the `\Q` and `\E` operators since all characters in between the two operators are treated as literal symbols.

You need to fix as follows:

```java
Regex("\\W*$label\\s*(.*)")
```